# ionic 2, run script on active page ONLY

Tags: typescript, angular, ionic2

I'm using tabs on ionic 2 with typescript.

I have a timer on tab 1 that checks the db every
second.

On tab 2, I have a timer that does the same

I don't want the timer script on tab one to run
if and when the user is on tab 2.

I've tried using the tab id

```
this.tab_id = nav.id

if(this.tab_id=='0-0' && this.tab_id!='0-1'){
  this.start()
  setInterval(()=>{
      this.start()
  },2000)
}
```

this doesn't work... the script in tab one keeps running after clicking tab 2

I also tried this on tab1.ts

```
ionViewDidEnter() {
this.start()
this.run_scripts = setInterval(()=>{
                        this.start()
                    },2000)
}
ionViewDidLeave() {
 clearInterval(this.run_scripts);
}
```

Any idea's how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Seem nothing wrong with this code. Maybe you have issue with other logic?

Answer (score 0):

went with viewDidEnter and viewDidLeave

```
ionViewDidEnter() {
  this.start()
  this.run_scripts = setInterval(()=>{
                          this.start()
                      },2000)
  this.runGame()

 }
 ionViewDidLeave() {
   clearInterval(this.run_scripts);
   clearInterval(this.int_players);
   clearInterval(this.game_timer);
 }
```